# Contributing to a JS Library

Tags: node.js, reactjs, reactstrap

I would like to contribute to the [Reactstrap library](https://github.com/reactstrap/reactstrap). I'm confused on how to setup my local env for development. I'm assuming that once I run `npm install` the library is compiled and any updates to the library code in `node_modules` won't be reflected.

What I've tried was following the docs by creating a new app using `create-react-app` and installing dependencies. I then added a few console log statements in the `componentWillMount` lifecycle in the library's Tooltip.js but they were never executed despite using the Tooltip component.

How do I set up my local env so I can develop a 3rd party library for React? This is not so much a question on how to contribute to this specific library. I have reached out to the team but I thought I could get faster guidance here.

Answer (score 1):

You should follow the directions in the Contributing section of the README file. If you have questions from there, you should contact the repo maintainers. If the Contributing section is unclear to you, chances are it is unclear to us, as well.

Comment: How about this more in general? My question doesn't only apply to this library. How about any node module/library?

Comment: The answer is the same. Always consult the project's contributing section or ask for clarification if needed.